# Help with logarithmic differentiation problems

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

$\mathbf{(1)}$ Find $y^{\prime}$ of $y=8^{\sqrt x}$

My try:

$\ln y=\ln(8)^{\sqrt x}$
$\dfrac{1}{y}y^{\prime}=\sqrt{x}\ln8$
I don't know how to proceed with right side.

$\mathbf{(2)}$ Find $y^{\prime}$ of $y=(t+4)(t+6)(t+7).$

This one I have no idea what to do so I don't have any work to show. My text says to use logarithmic differentiation, but still I don't how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: For (1), you can substitute $y=8^{\sqrt{x}}$ in the LHS and rewrite to get $y'$. For (2), the RHS is $1$, except when $t\in\{-4,-6,-7\}$, so $y'=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Note that $\ln\left(a^{b}\right) = b\ln\left(a\right)$ so, for $y = 8^{\sqrt{x}}$, $\ln y = \sqrt{x}\ln\left(8\right)$. Differentiating, we get $\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{\ln\left(8\right)}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and so $y'=\ln\left(8\right)\frac{8^{\sqrt{x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

**(2)** I assume you're required to use logarithmic differentiation for this.

Remember that $\ln\left(ab\right)=\ln a + \ln b$. Therefore, for $y = \left(t+4\right)\left(t+6\right)\left(t+7\right)$, we have $\ln y = \ln\left(t+4\right) + \ln\left(t+6\right) + \ln\left(t+7\right)$. From there, differentiating, we have $\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{1}{t+4}+\frac{1}{t+6}+\frac{1}{t+7}$. Therefore, $y' = \left(t+4\right)\left(t+6\right)\left(t+7\right)\left(\frac{1}{t+4}+\frac{1}{t+6}+\frac{1}{t+7}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln y=\sqrt{x}\ln8$, so $\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\ln8$. Therefore $$y'=\frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}}\ln8=\frac{8^{\sqrt{x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}\ln8$$

For the second question, except for $t=-4,-6,-7$, you may take logarithm of both sides and note that $\frac{1}{dt}\ln(t+a)=\frac{1}{t+a}$, and then carry on as above. However you can solve this problem by simple differentiation then you need not even take care of whether $t$ takes the aforementioned values or not.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the second question.

Answer (score 1):

For (2), you get 
$$
\ln y=\ln (t+4)+\ln (t+6)+\ln (t+7)
$$
Differentiating gives
$$
\frac{ y'}y=\frac1{t+4}+\frac1{t+6}+\frac1{t+7}
$$
thus
\begin{align}
y'&=y\left(\frac1{t+4}+\frac1{t+6}+\frac1{t+7}\right)\\
&=(t+4)(t+6)(t+7)\left(\frac1{t+4}+\frac1{t+6}+\frac1{t+7}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

In the first problem, you got down to $\ln y = \ln(8)^{\sqrt{x}}$ which is correct, but you made a mistake in the next line. On the left you differentiated, but on the right you rewrote $\ln(8)^{\sqrt{x}}$ as $\sqrt{x}\ln(8)$. While it is true that $\ln(8)^{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}\ln(8)$, the equation you wrote is false as you did not differentiate both the left and right hand sides of the equation. I recommend first simplifying the right hand side so that you obtain $\ln y = \sqrt{x}\ln(8)$ and now proceed to differentiate.

The process for all logarithmic differentiation problems is the same:

- take logarithms of both sides,
- simplify using the properties of the logarithm ($\ln(AB) = \ln(A) + \ln(B)$, etc.),
- differentiate both sides (making sure to use implicit differentiation
  where necessary),
- rearrange for $y'$,
- replace $y$ by the corresponding expression in terms of $x$.

These steps should allow you to complete the first problem, as well as begin the second. Feel free to ask for help if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, plug in the expression you started with for $y$ and simplify. For 2, I would not normally use logaritmic differentiation-I would just use the product rule.  Quick and easy.  But if must, you have the same approach:  Assuming $t \gt -4, \log y= \log (t+4) +\dots$, differentiate to get $\frac {y'}y$, replace the $y$, multiply out, and get the same answer.